maximum number of parallel project builds property affect
I want to speed up the build time in Visual Studio, and I discovered the 'Maximum number of parallel project builds' setting from the following link.
text
Here's how to find it:

Go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions.
In the Build and Run property page, adjust the value for Maximum number of parallel project builds and click OK.

I have 4 physical cores and 8 logical processors, and the default setting for this property was 8. I increased it to 16.Even though I only have one project in the solution, This change improved the build speed, but I’m curious about how it works and whether there could be any adverse effects.
